# Solution to $y''=y $ satisfying $y(0)=2$ and $y'(0) = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the solution to $y''=y $ satisfying $y(0)=2$ and $y'(0) = 0$.

I'm struggling with this basic question... any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The characteristic equation of $y''=y$ is $r^2-1=0$ and the roots are $r_1=1, r_2=-1$
then the general solution is
$$y(x)=Ae^x+Be^{-x}$$
Now with $y(0)=2$ and $y'(0)=0$ we find
$$A+B=2\qquad;\qquad
A-B=0$$
so $A=1$ and $B=1$.

Comment: So the answer then is y(x) = e^x + e^-x?

Comment: Yes it is and it's the unique solution.